# Adding AdditionalIncludeDirectories makes project unable to import from standard library

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a project in Visual Studio that is set up with the following architecture:

- src

  - main.cpp
  - math.cpp
- include

  - math.h

math.h contains function prototypes for the functions found in math.cpp. When using #include "math.h" after adding include\ to the project's C/C++ Additional Include Directories, I find the compiler is not able to find the standard library. I get several errors like this:

```
...
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\cmath(261,18): error C2039: 'sinhf': is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\cmath(261,23): error C3861: 'sinhf': identifier not found
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\cmath(265,18): error C2039: 'sqrtf': is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include\cmath(265,23): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
```

Of course, I can successfully include include\ by using #include "..\include\math.h" but I know there must be a way to tell Visual Studio to look in \include for files to include. Any ideas on what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: It's not a good idea to name your own header file exactly the same as one of the [C compatibility headers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header#C_compatibility_headers).

Comment: Wow. Thank you @heapunderrun! That seemed to work. Now to read up on C compatibility headers.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)